# jQuery FadeIn Delay Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble figuring out what is causing my issue. If you go to my site and choose a random plant. Lets say for example you click Vegetables and then Bean Bush Plant there is a 3 second delay and then the grass image fades in. This will only happen if you reload the page and start from the beginning. Once the grass fades in and you hit the back button in the webpage (not the web browser back button) and click any plant there is not delay issue. The 3 second delay only happens after you reload the page. Can anyone tell me why this is occurring? Here's the site:

http://andrewhnovak.com/Botany/index.html#

Comment: I don't get any major delays when clicking on your site?

Comment: What browser you trying this on? I don't see any delays.

Comment: please post the minimum amount of code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: No problems on my end. Chrome, FF, Opera all running this with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because in your `home.js` file you have an initial 5 seconds fade in for the grass

```
$("#grass").fadeTo(5000, 8);
$("#grass1").fadeTo(5000, 8);
```

So if you move quickly before it has faded in, you have to wait until it completes its fade.